# How to write missing dev script in React?

Tags: reactjs, npm

When I run docker-compose up on my project the backend runs fine but the frontend fails and keeps restarting. It cites "npm ERR! missing script: dev" as the error. Now I am using react and dev isnt one of the default scripts when creating an app so Im not sure how to write it.
This is my package.json file.

```
{
"name": "frontend",
"version": "0.3.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1",
"web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --passWithNoTests",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
  "react-app",
  "react-app/jest"
]
},
"browserslist": {
"production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
]
}
}
```

I figured I would write it just like all the others, so I wrote " "dev": "react-scripts dev" " but it did not work.

docker-compose.yml file below

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
  ports:
    - "8050:8000"
  volumes:
    - .:/frontend
  environment:
    CI: 'true'
  restart: always
backend:
  build:
    context: ./backend
  ports:
    - "4050:5000"
  volumes:
    - ./backend:/opt/app
  restart: always
```

frontend Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
COPY . /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: Can you add your docker-compose.yml and any Dockerfile you've used for your react.js app? I suspect a change in the Dockerfile is the easiest way to achieve what you're looking for....

Comment: `react-scripts start` starts the development server. `"dev": "react-scripts start"`

Comment: Added the files @JayAchar

Comment: Should that replace the "start" script or just add that one to the end? @cbr

Comment: @Jaakko Your frontend's dockerfile looks alright and it uses the `start` script. Did you used to have `CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]` in there? If so do `docker-compose build frontend` to rebuild the image and `docker-compose up -d` again. If it still complains about missing `dev`, are you sure the error is coming from the frontend container and not from the backend container?

Comment: I tried that but gives the same error. Im fairly certain its the frontend because if I run docker-compose up and actually look at the output the backend runs fine and starts, its the frontend that fails and keeps restarting over and over. @cbr

Comment: Ah. You should add `RUN npm install` before `CMD`. And/or fix your frontend service's volume mount path - should it be `- ./frontend:/opt/app`?

Comment: Still nothing... Not sure what it could be anymore been on this for a while now. @cbr

Comment: And if you add the dev script I mentioned earlier in addition to the other existing scripts, does it work? And you did `docker-compose down && docker-compose build frontend && docker-compose up -d` to make sure it actually changed the image?

Comment: Yea i did down and then built it again. Still getting the error though. @cbr

Comment: Honestly, there's nothing here that would run the script "dev". All I can think of is trying to set an `image` name for both services, and maybe try changing `build: context: ./frontend` to `build: ./frontend`.

Comment: I'd also try running the image you just built and enter into a shell e.g. `docker-compose run frontend sh` and try running `npm run start` and if it doesn't work, `cat package.json` to verify that it's what you're expecting!